# When I am running Execute SonarQube Scanner on Jenkins, job always fails

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am running Execute SonarQube Scanner on Jenkins, but the job always fails.

The job log shows:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:
>   sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project
>   helpRequestMgmtUI: Not authorized. Please check the properties
>   sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]

In job configuration, I added the following into Analysis properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=org.sonarqube:javascript-lcov-sq-scanner
sonar.projectName=My project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.language=js
sonar.sources=webapp

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.javascript.coveragePlugin=jacoco

sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
```

In the last two lines I have already added user name and password but it does not work for executing `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603`

However, the SonarQube dashboard is created successfully.

How do I avoid this authorization exception, when analysing my project?

Comment: If the dashboard has been created, then that means the project exists in SonarQube. Double-check its permissions to make sure that admin has permissions to execute analysis.

Comment: Have you configured the SonarQube server connection settings on Jenkins configuration?

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed this issue. I changed Jenkins job from Maven to non-Maven job and this issue never comes out again. But I'm still wondering why this issue happens for only Maven job. I'm using Jenkins version 2.46.3.